# Nesting CSS Elements (styling a link within a header)

Tags: css, css-selectors

I'm a bit of a CSS noob.

I'm trying to create a rule to ensure all html anchors sitting inside `<h3>` tags don't display an underline (and also display some other color properties). This is what I have but it doesn't work:

```
<h3><a href="#">Turn of underline etc</a></h3>

h3 a, a:active, a:visited a:hover {
    text-decoration:none;
    color:#000000;
}
```

Answer (score 3):

as per your code, you need to use `h3` four times in all like so

```
h3 a, h3 a:active, h3 a:visited, h3 a:hover {
    text-decoration:none;
    color:#000000;
}
```

the way you have it now, the active, visited and hover states don't apply to the h3 "specifically"

Answer (score 2):

This should do it:

```
h3 a {
    text-decoration:none;
    color:#000;
}
```

**Live demo:** http://jsfiddle.net/simevidas/7A2JX/

Comment: Thanks for both of your answers. It works in isolation but I have a separate global html anchor style also defined. It seems to override the above code. How can I prevent this? This is the global anchor code: 

a:link, a:active {
    color: #1d5298;
    text-decoration: underline;
}

Comment: You have two options: Make Sime's definition more specific (by adding the pseudo classes :link and :active to them), or adding an !important flag to the end of each property.

Answer (score 2):

You can do something like follows.

Do this for when a hyperlink inside an h3 is hovered with the mousy.

```
h3 a:hover {
    color: #FFFF20;
}
```

And this for the actual styling (when not hovered), the text-decoration should take away your underline.

```
h3 a {
    text-decoration: none;
    color: #EBE6C8;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

you are missing a comma after a:visited.

Comment: how does that answer the question??

Comment: well unless you are wanting to style all the a:hover's inside of a:visited's it won't work.  just added this in case you missed that. oh wait you aren't even the one asking the question. why are you harping on me again?

Answer (score 0):

If you want to avoid conflict or override with your other anchor tag. It's better to add a class attribute. If you prefer not to add a class make sure that the CSS you've added called after other CSS with the same tag.

Sample code with class

CSS

```
h3 a.someClass {
    text-decoration: none;
    color: #000000;
}

//If you want style on hover do something like this
a:hover.h3-anchor {
    color:#FF0000;
}
```

HTML

```
<h3><a class="someClass" href="#">Some Text</a></h3>
```

Base on your comment to Sime, I'm not sure why its overriding where the anchor tag style is separate. It will override unless you do something like this  body a {} or other block which your < a > is inside of it.

Answer (score 0):

Also, if you are contradicting an overarching style (style set for your standard tags), you may need to add "!important" to the tag you are altering.

Using your example:

```
<h3><a href="#">Turn of underline etc</a></h3>

h3 a {
    text-decoration:none !important;
    color:#000000;
    }
```

Hope this helps!